# Split String dynamic using Python

Tags: pandas

Is this possible to change into a loop or any function that I can use?

```
df['BRAND 1'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[0]
df['BRAND 2'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[1]
df['BRAND 3'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[2]
df['BRAND 4'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[3]
df['BRAND 5'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[4]
df['BRAND 6'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[5]
df['BRAND 7'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[6]
df['BRAND 8'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[7]
df['BRAND 9'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[8]
df['BRAND 10'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here loops are not necessary, add `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and then change columns names in list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
df1 = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|', expand=True)
df1.columns = [f'BRAND {i + 1}' for i in range(len(df1.columns))]

df = df.join(df1)
```

Loop is also possible, use:

```
for i in range(10):
    df[f'BRAND {i + 1}'] = df['SAMPLES'].str.split('|').str[i]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply  the 1st code works  while the 2nd code  it displayed  'BRAND {i + 1}' as a column.

Comment: @Trunks - You are right, I forget for `f` in `f'BRAND {i + 1}'`. Answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks Brother, the second script  got my expected result.